# HTML email signature showing only file names in reply messages (Outlook)

Tags: html, image, email, outlook, signature

I've created HTML email signatures to be used in Outlook. They look fine in the first email, but in the chain of replies, the images in the signature shows as `<image005.png>` Also, the links are underlined in blue occasionally. Any ideas why this is? (If it matters, the email settings are set to HTML not Plain Text.)

```
<br />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<table width='320' id="sig" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<tr>
<td width="86" style="width:86px;margin:0;padding:0;">
<a href='http://urbanpalate.com' style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://urbanpalate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/email_logo.jpg" alt="UrbanPalate" style="border:none;width:86px;"></a>
</td>

<td width="10" style="width:10px;">&nbsp;</td>  

<td valign='top' style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<table id="sig2" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="padding:0;margin:0;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<td style="margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:2px;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;font-size:14px;white-space:nowrap;">
<strong><a href="mailto:geoff@urbanpalate.com" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#333333"><span style="color:#ff893b">Geoffrey Bernstein </span></a></strong><span style="color:#505050;"></span>
<span style="color:#333333;"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;color:#333333;">
<td style="margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:2px;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;font-size:14px;white-space:nowrap;">
<a href="http://urbanpalate.com" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#333333;"><span style="color:#333333">Urban Palate<span style="color:#333333"></span></a><span style="color:#505050"> | </span>
<a href="http://goo.gl/maps/uH28q" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#333333;"><span style="color:#333333">Los Angeles, CA</span></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;color:#333333">
<td style="margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:2px;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;font-size:14px;white-space:nowrap;">
<a href="tel:877-402-2002" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;"><span style="color:#333333">p 877</span><span style="color:#505050">.</span><span style="color:#333333">402</span><span style="color:#505050">.</span><span style="color:#333333">2002</span></a>
<span style="color:#505050;">|</span>
<a href="tel:213-236-0951" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;"><span style="color:#333333">f 213</span><span style="color:#333333">.</span><span style="color:#333333">236</span><span style="color:#505050">.</span><span style="color:#333333">0951</span></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;color:#333333;">
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:2px;font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;font-size:14px;white-space:nowrap;">
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/pages/Urban-Palate/221795937949264?ref=ts&fref=ts' style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://urbanpalate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/facebook.png" alt="UrbanPalate" style="border:none;width:22px;padding-right:4px;"></a>
<a href='https://twitter.com/urbanpalatela' style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://urbanpalate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/twitter.png" alt="UrbanPalate" style="border:none;width:22px;padding-right:4px;"></a>
<a href='http://pinterest.com/UrbanPalateLA/' style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://urbanpalate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/pinterest.png" alt="UrbanPalate" style="border:none;width:22px;padding-right:4px;"></a>
<a href='http://instagrid.me/urbanpalatela/' style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://urbanpalate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/instagram.png" alt="UrbanPalate" style="border:none;width:22px;"></a>
</td>
</tr>   
</table>
</td>
<tr>
</table>
<br />
&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officesetupdeploy/thread/7a14c86d-a2ee-444a-8020-1693d4dea1e4) to be helpful.
Basically, in Outlook, go to Options > Mail > Signatures. On the right, new messages default to your signatures. The Replies/forwards setting defaults to none- make sure that setting is selected to the appropriate signature.